# How to use 2 power supplies in my scheme?

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am building a device to send a signal from Raspberry Pi GPIO to a vibration motor. Here is how it should work: the RPI outputs 0v or 3.3v, and when it outputs 3.3v, the vibration motor should vibrate. I figured out that RPi GPIO current is too small for this vibration motor, so I decided to use some external power supply (in my case, 9v battery), so 9v should be sent to vibration motor when GPIO outputs 3.3v. The problem is I don't understand how to connect it properly.

I guess I should use the transistor key with base connected to the RPi GPIO output and base and emitter connected to the 9v. But it somehow doesn't work the way I want it.

Can you help me with it? I'm completely lost.

Comment: what is the motor rating?

Comment: General rule of thumb, never ever connect a motor to any of the io pins of the arduino/raspberry pi, you will damage the board.

Comment: @Sada93 I really don't know (I didn't buy it, it was given to me at university). And what I need to connect it to if not to Rpi output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual procedure I use for motors is through a H-Bridge. But since a vibration motor isn't bidirectional I believe we can use just one switch in the following configuration. (I'm assuming its a 3V motor).

[image]

Instead of the D3 pin used on the arduino you can use the GPIO pin from the RPi. Furthermore you can also use the 5V output from the Raspberry pi for testing, otherwise i usually like to use an external battery for this.

Source for further reading:

http://learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Vibration-motor-circuit.php

Comment: This seems to be the thing I was looking for.

Comment: Can I use it to power more than 1 vibration motor (from more than 1 output)?

Comment: Yeah you can, you have to utilize a separate GPIO pin and program it accordingly. One caution though, if you are running more than one motor use an external battery. You dont want to pull too much current from the Raspberry Pi's power output.

Comment: Is there any schematics how to connect, for example, 2 vibration motors and control them independently using 2 GPIOs? I guess this will be somehow different from the scheme with 1 vibration motor and 1 GPIO

Comment: If you want to control them independently, no the schematic will not be different. Just cascade another circuit in parallel with this. (Dont cascade the motor cascade the entire circuit, using another GPIO pin). You will need to buy another set of each of the components excepting the RPi of course.